# How To Write A Parameterized Query With @databricks/sql To Hive

Tags: javascript, sql, hive, databricks

I'm looking to write parameterized queries with the @databricks/sql npm package targeting a Hive database. With Postgres, I would do something like so

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id == $1', [123]).then(res => {
  const data = res.rows;
});
```

With the @databricks/sql npm package I have the ability to query with the supplied code like this

```
const queryString = `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = ${id}` // Bad
const queryOperation = await session.executeStatement(queryString, { runAsync: true });
await utils.waitUntilReady(
  queryOperation,
  false,
  () => {}
);

await utils.fetchAll(
  queryOperation
);

await queryOperation.close();

const result = utils.getResult(
  queryOperation
).getValue();
```

I'm struggling to find documentation on how I might pass in arguments instead of a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Would this python widget work for you? If not, then I can remove this answer.

Command 1: (defining the variables)

```
%python
dbutils.widgets.text('score_date', '2021-01-01')
```

Command 2: (a query)

```
%sql 
select whatever
from database.table_name
where months_between('$score_date', service_date) <= 12
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have explicitly noted it but my biggest concern is sql injection and getting the driver defenses that come with parameterizing a query as opposed to giving a crafted string literal. I can add additional checks to our input but also want the safety net of the driver.

The python is thought provoking but our implementation is in Javascript.